# How is MultiValueDictKeyError and AttributeError related in Django here?

Tags: python, json, django

I have a function in Django that I am trying to solve from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528757/rendering-redirecting-django-in-ajax-success-function). While trying out my own solutions, I have made significant updates but I encounter an error.

I'm trying this out right now:

```
def view_routes(request, query=None):
routes = None

if query is None:
    routes = Route.objects.all()

else:
    #View: Routes in Queried Boundary
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        json_feature = json.loads(request.GET.get('geo_obj', False))
        #json_feature = json.loads(request.GET['geo_obj'])
        geom = make_geometry_from_feature(json_feature)
        routes = Route.objects.filter(wkb_geometry__within=geom[0])
        print("Total Routes Filtered: " + str(Route.objects.filter(wkb_geometry__within=geom[0]).count()))

        #Render to Django View
        routes_json = serialize('geojson', routes, fields=('route_type', 'route_long', 'route_id', 'wkb_geometry',))
        routes_geojson = json.loads(routes_json)
        routes_geojson.pop('crs', None)
        routes_geojson = json.dumps(routes_geojson)

        #return render(request, 'plexus/view_routes.html', {'routes':routes})
        return redirect('routes_view', query)
```

I am having trouble switching/commenting out between these two lines:

> json_feature = json.loads(request.GET.get('geo_obj', False))
>
> json_feature = json.loads(request.GET['geo_obj'])

Both presents an error respectively:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bool'
>
> django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'geo_obj'"

Edited function with AJAX inside:

```
function sendQueryData(url, query){
    url =url.replace('query' , query);

    if (query === ""){
        alert("City Input Required");
    }else{
        if(geo_obj === null){
            alert("Click Search Button...")
        }else{

            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                },
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    'geo_obj' : JSON.stringify(geo_obj)
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    window.location.href = url;
                    //var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#list-group').html();
                    //$('#list-group').html(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Request Failed' + textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: request object does not contain "geo_obj" in it. That's what this error message is conveying.

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan but if I print it out there's an object being passed via ajax (?)

Comment: Could be a list then, please try "request.GET.getlist('geo_obj')"

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I've edited, I included my ajax function here. I pass geo_obj, JSON.stringify-ied

Comment: is geo_obj a JS object or string?  a sample of geo_obj would also be helpful!

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan already a string after stringified. Alright I'll just upload it

Comment: If your geo_obj is a string you don't have to apply JSON.stringify, otherwise your approach should be perfect.

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan h it worked. There's another error but at least it changed. It says that URI is too long now. I'll search for a solution on this one. I'll also understand what just happened now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json.loads(request.body)` if you are passing raw JSON, `request.GET['foo']` is for form-encoded data

Comment: I'll try this. This is the first time I'm going to use this in my project if ever

Comment: actually no, I'll add my ajax here so people doesn't have to look at the other link. I'm passing it JSON.strinigy-ied. Error trying yours is: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'